# How do trampolinists rebound to the same height off their back?

Tags: trampolining

I suspect the answer to this is easier than I think, but a common trick (at least in videos online) involves falling (not jumping), landing on one's back, and then rebounding to the same position as where you started. Entropy being what it is, you generally only get a fraction of energy back on a bounce, and landing on one's back seems like it would dissipate even more energy, with little opportunity to "jump" to regain the lost energy. What's the trick to it?